# Div element wider than its content

Tags: html

[image]

I just can't find out why there's extra space(red line) inside the div element.

The left element is exactly the same but doesn't have this issue.

code:

```
<div class="detailsSection2">
  <div class="profile-info-row">
    <div class="profile-info-name-short"><br><br> 11111111111:
    </div>
    <div class="profile-info-value" style="border:none;"><br><br>
      <span style="border-bottom:1px dotted #D5E4F1; padding-bottom: 5px;">
         1111111111
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-info-name-short"><br><br> 11111111111:
    </div>
    <div class="profile-info-value" style="border:none;"><br><br>
      <span style="border-bottom:1px dotted #D5E4F1; padding-bottom: 5px;">
          **
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="profile-info-row">
    <div class="profile-info-name-short">ABC: </div>
    <div class="profile-info-value" style="border:none;">
      <span style="border-bottom:1px dotted #D5E4F1; padding-bottom: 5px;">
         **                                        
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-info-row">
      <div class="profile-info-name-short">
        1111111&nbsp;111:
      </div>
      <div class="profile-info-value" style="border:none;">
        <span style="border-bottom:1px dotted #D5E4F1; padding-bottom: 5px;">
           Enabled
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fz14u0dh/

Comment: Nopes, it's [not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omHZU.png)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have an extra row in your html:

```css
.profile-info-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.profile-info-name-short {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 4px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #485866;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.profile-info-value {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 6px 4px 6px 6px;
  /* border-top: 1px dotted #D5E4F1; */
}

.profile-info-name-short {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 4px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #485866;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="detailsSection2">
  <div class="profile-info-row">
    <div class="profile-info-name-short"><br><br> 11111111111:
    </div>
    <div class="profile-info-value" style="border:none;"><br><br>
      <span style="border-bottom:1px dotted #D5E4F1; padding-bottom: 5px;">
         1111111111
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-info-name-short"><br><br> 11111111111:
    </div>
    <div class="profile-info-value" style="border:none;"><br><br>
      <span style="border-bottom:1px dotted #D5E4F1; padding-bottom: 5px;">
          **
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="profile-info-row">
    <div class="profile-info-name-short">ABC: </div>
    <div class="profile-info-value" style="border:none;">
      <span style="border-bottom:1px dotted #D5E4F1; padding-bottom: 5px;">
         **                                        
      </span>
    </div>
    <!--                   REMOVE THIS <div class="profile-info-row"> -->
    <div class="profile-info-name-short">
      1111111&nbsp;111:
    </div>
    <div class="profile-info-value" style="border:none;">
      <span style="border-bottom:1px dotted #D5E4F1; padding-bottom: 5px;">
           Enabled
        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- DELETE THIS TOO </div> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your divs are behaving like table rows: [image]

Your third top element is longer because it's matching the width of row cells below it.

Comment: As Pete correctly pointed out, you have an extra row in there that's messing things up